# User profile information store in JWT or use API

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

In my application, I have separate microservices for user authentication and user profile information. The user authentication service is using Spring Security OAuth2/JWT. Once a user successfully logs in, a JWT token is issued with the user unique identifier.

My query is how other services should retrieve user profile information. Should I put this information (such as first name, last name etc) into the JWT token or should I create an API on the user profile service which retrieves the user profile information once the token is retrieved?

Any best practice advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far most approaches i've seen was to store only user's login in JWT token and have another service which gives you other needed informations by login, and this seems like the best approach to me (in case of any security leak's login is the only thing that can be stolen, and not user's first or last name).

Comment: Thanks Kamil, I think the API route is the way to go. It's another request once you retrieve the token but it gives the advantage to provide the user's full profile without having to take out sensitive data that you might not want to put in the JWT token.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is important to highlight that OAuth2 is intended to be an **authorization** protocol rather than **authentication**.

OpenID Connect solves this problem by separating the identity (ID_Token) and the authorization (access token) into two different tokens for the application to consume. Rather than implementing your own, may I suggest that you consider OpenID Connect?

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar discussions with my team while working on the authentication microservice. Though it's important to understand that JWT is an encoding and not an encryption so it's always advised not to keep sensitive data in JWT. Though the items that we decide to keep in JWT should also depend on the problem statement we are solving. There can be use cases where saving the Username or email id is not a sensitive information and you may want to keep that in JWT just to avoid an extra API call.